# What is "the flesh under the cheeks & chin, before the neck" called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Look at these picture:

[image]

[image]

What is "**the flesh under the chicks & chin & before the neck**" called?

Is it still called "**the under chin or under jaw**"? For example, The man is thin not fat & I said to him "**you   have a rash on / under your chin / jaw**"

**Note:** you can see this part of the face clearly if he /she is overweight.

Answer (score 5):

It is sometimes referred to as "jowls", or, when it is particularly pronounced, a "double-chin". As excessive skin in this area is sometimes a sign of being overweight, having jowls is not usually desirable, but the latter expression "double-chin" is considered particularly insulting.

For non-overweight persons, this area of the body is not normally pronounced, and there isn't a particular general name for it. Looking at some medical charts, it *may* be the "submandibular triangle", but this is not in general use. As far as most non-medically trained people are concerned, the chin ends where the neck begins. If you wanted to specify that area as opposed to the most pronounced part of the chin (the mandible) you would perhaps say "under the chin".

Answer (score 2):

"Under the chin in the midline" -The space coincides with the anatomic region termed the "submental triangle"